# preload data after sessionAuthenticated at application route globally

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

After calling a custom **authenticate** method at login route, the action **sessionAuthenticated** is triggered at the application level (ApplicationRouteMixin).

ie:

```
sessionAuthenticated() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    let _this = this;
    return this_loadUser().catch(function() {
        _this.get('session').invalidate();

    });

}
```

This works, however, if I want to preload extra data, **sessionAuthenticated** does not wait until all the promises are resolved.
And since the **beforeModel** and **afterModel** hooks were already initially at the application route level, the only way this works reliably is when refreshing the page while session is active (logged in) which calls the beforeModel and afterModel hooks.

In short; when at the login route, calling authenticate, after successful authenticate the sessionAuthenticated action is triggered at the application route, but **with extra data needed to be preloaded globally**, at the application route level. The sessionAuthenticated doesn't see to wait until all promises are resolved.

NOTE: the answer is correct, however, the call to super will not work since Ember does not support calling super on asynchronous blocks, only synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call this._super **after** your promise was fulfilled/rejected. Something like this:

```
sessionAuthenticated() {   
    let _this = this;
    return this_loadUser().catch(function() {
        _this.get('session').invalidate();
    }).finally(function() {
        _this._super(...arguments);
    });

}
```

Comment: Yes, this should work, but only half-way. I have tried this previously as well. The promises resolve, but then the call to _this._super() does nothing. The solution is to copy the sessionAuthenticated method relevant code into the finally/then block, which makes the call to transition. I'm not sure why the call to super does not execute in this case, weird. Nevertheless, your answer is close to the answer.

Comment: @user3044258 In this case I would try `_this._super.call(_this, ...arguments);` to pass a correct `this` to parent method

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. Unfortunately, Ember does not support calling super on asynchronous blocks. Only synchronous blocks are supported.

Comment: Found a way around it: let _super = this._super; and then _super(...arguments) inside the block

Comment: LOL, that doesn't work either. I jumped to conclusion.